# Lines (NOT TEXT) added to single cells of two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

Need to place 5-6 straight horizonta lines (NOT TEXT) in two single cells in two columns of an Excel Spreadsheet, the existing document has this, but I haven't been able to duplicate it, I have searched U-Tube to not avail.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a cell, enter:

```
="_________" & CHAR(10) & "_________"& CHAR(10) & "_________"& CHAR(10) & "_________"& CHAR(10) & "_________"& CHAR(10) & "_________"
```

and turn on wrap:

[image]